# extending express application interface

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I am trying to extend the expressjs Application interface using declaration merging as explained in the express type definitions

```
declare module Express {

    // These open interfaces may be extended in an application-specific manner via declaration merging.
    // See for example method-override.d.ts (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/method-override/method-override.d.ts)
    export interface Request { }
    export interface Response { }
    export interface Application { }
}
```

So, my app.ts looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="typings/express/express.d.ts" />

declare module Express {
    export interface Application {
        testA: string;
    }
    export interface Request {
        testR: string;
    }
}

import express = require('express');

var    app  = express();

app.testA = "why not?";
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.testR = "xxx";
})
```

I get the errors:

"Property testA does not exist on type Express"

"Property testR does not exist on type Request"

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried moving `declare module Express` to another `*.d.ts` file? For some reason that may help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using modules, declaration merging won't happen here. In `app.ts` there isn't an `Express` module to merge with so it's making a completely separate module definition. You need to move the code...

```
declare module Express {
    export interface Application {
        testA: string;
    }
    export interface Request {
        testR: string;
    }
}
```

...into a `.d.ts` file so that the interfaces are merged with the ones in `express.d.ts`.